# Audio timescale-pitch modification - Open source examples?

Tags: java, c++, c, audio

Is anyone aware of any open source libraries/implementations of real-time timescale-pitch modification algorithms?

Comment: Am I the only one who has no idea what a timescale-pitch modification is? :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_timescale-pitch_modification But really, if you don't know you don't have to comment.

Comment: It's basically changing the tempo without changing the pitch, or changing the pitch without changing the tempo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Scaletempo](http://scaletempo.sourceforge.net/0/) might do what you want.  [MPlayer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPlayer) uses it.

Answer (score 4):

[DSP Dimension](http://www.dspdimension.com/technology-licensing/dirac2/) provides some good tutorials on [pitch-shifting and time-scale modification](http://www.dspdimension.com/admin/time-pitch-overview/) techniques. There are plenty of links to related material (various libraries, tutorials and implementations) as well as an open source Fourier-based implementation in C++ (check the Download section).

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Rubberband](http://breakfastquay.com/rubberband/) library.  It's GPL-licensed and includes a library as well as CLI apps that use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to that list by the way, SoundTouch C++ library can do it: http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/

Comment: You can slow down using soundtouch but when you slow down to 0.5 it will generate noise. Audio will not smooth enough.